# Different outcome with the same regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

I just learning Python and the regular "language". But I just encountered this problem which I can't answer. Some help or recommendations would be helpful.

```
import re
m = " text1 \abs{foo} text2 text3 \L{E.F} text4 "


def separate_mycmd(cmd,m):
    math_cmd = re.compile(cmd)
    math = math_cmd.findall(m)
    text = math_cmd.split(m)
    return(math,text)

(math,text) = separate_mycmd(r'\abs',m)

print math  # ['\x07bs']
print text  # [' text1 ', '{foo} text2 text3 \\L{E.F} text4 ']

(math,text) = separate_mycmd(r'\L',m)

print math  # **Question:** Just ['L'] and not ['\\L'] or ['\L]
print text  # [' text1 \x07bs{foo} text2 text3 \\', '{E.F} text4 ']
            # **Question:** why the \\ after text3 ?
```

I don't understand the output from the last call. My related questions are in the comments.

Thanks in advance,
    Ulrich

Comment: If you are just learning Python, ignore Python 2 and start with Python 3. (I can tell you are using Python 2 because you are using a `print` statement, not the `print` function.)

Comment: Thats true: Python2 on my iMac. I can install Python 3 and check my problem.

Comment: what is "m" in the call "separate_mycmd(r'\abs',m)"?

Comment: Sorry, I have added the string m

Answer (score 0):

You want to match on `"\\L"`, not `\L`, giving you:

```
> (math,text) = separate_mycmd(r'\\L',m)

> print math
['\\L']

> print text
[' text1 \x07bs{foo} text2 text3 ', '{E.F} text4 ']
```

You also probably wanted to use `\\a` as well. And you probably also wanted to use it in the string you're searching, giving:

```
m = " text1 \\abs{foo} text2 text3 \\L{E.F} text4 "
```

Comment: Ok, but why is it different to the first \abs case?

Comment: You actually wanted it there too. The difference is that `\a` means something in python strings (namely, the ascii bell character), while `\L` doesn't (and sort of defaults to `\\L`). https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

Comment: I thought I could overcome this problem by using r‘\abs‘ for example. The doc I am using.